# Trying To Download Subversion Code with Python's urllib2 module = Fail

Tags: python, svn

I am trying to download code from a Subversion repository without using the `svn` Subversion program. I am using Python's urllib2 module instead. Below is my script. The problem with this script is that it returns a web page of sorts and not the actual source-code. I can see the links to the source-code but not the actual source-code.

**Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can download the actual source-code from Subversion with urllib2?**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import urllib2


def sub():
    theurl = 'https://Intranet-Server/svn/FancySoftware/trunk/'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

    passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)

    authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

    opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
    print "OPENER :", opener

    urllib2.install_opener(opener)

    pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)
    print "PAGEHANDLE :", pagehandle
    return pagehandle 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ret = sub()
    for line in ret:
         print line
```

Comment: Visit `https://Intranet-Server/svn/FancySoftware/trunk/` in your browser. Do you see the source code, or do you see a web page? Try something like `https://Intranet-Server/svn/FancySoftware/trunk/myproject/src/main.c` That should give you source code.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks Rob for the input. How do I recursively download all the code though?

Comment: I'd use `svn export` or `svn co`. If you choose to do it with python invoking `urllib2.urlopen`, you'll probably need a recursive function or a dynamic list of files to download.

Comment: `svn co` works but I am trying not to use Subversion. I maybe be able to write a regular expression to download all the files, but this is probably beyond my current skills.

Comment: If I specify the absolute path to the file I can download a single file but this is very far from where I would like the script to be. Thanks for the help Rob. I would not of thought of specifying the absolute path to the file.